# How to end a loop in python after user presses all answers?

Tags: python, loops

```
# loop
while True:
  inp = raw_input()
  if inp == "":pres= input("What would you like to know about me? AGE, JOKE, FACT")
  if pres in {'AGE', 'Age','age'}:
    print("I was birthed from my mother 87 years ago. Press enter to continue")
  if pres in {'JOKE','Joke','joke'}:
    print("Where do polar bears keep their money?")
    import time
    time.sleep(2)
    print("In a snow bank! Press enter to continue")
  if pres in {'FACT','Fact','fact'}:
    print("Hippopotamus's have pink spit! Press enter to continue")

# end of loop
```

I am trying to end this loop, but using break at the end doesn't seem to work. I want the loop to end after the user has input all three options; age, joke, and fact.

Comment: Can you please correct the indentation of your code? Also, add an option which changes the 'True' variable to false at a certain point, probably at the end of the loop.

Comment: You need to change the conditional on the while loop.. Your current condition is an infinite loop.

`True` is always `True`.

Comment: A better way to check the input is `if inp.lower() == 'fact':`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code has done nothing to track which items have been chosen.  Your loop condition does nothing to check when it should exit.  In general, you want your `while` condition to control the loop exit; this application doesn't warrant a deep-seated `break`.

I recommend that you set three flags (Boolean variables), one for each choice.  Set the appropriate flag when you see each item.  Here's an example for the loop head and the addition to one clause:

```
joke = False
age = False
fact = False

while not (joke and age and fact):
    ...
    if pres.lower() == "age":
        age = True
    ...
```

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 4):

You could record the state of user queries in a set:

```
chosen = set()
while len(chosen) < 3:
    inp = raw_input()
    if inp == "":
        pres = input("What would you like to know about me? AGE, JOKE, FACT")
    if pres in {'AGE', 'Age','age'}:
        print("I was birthed from my mother 87 years ago. Press enter to continue")
        chosen.add("age")
    if pres in {'JOKE','Joke','joke'}:
        print("Where do polar bears keep their money?")
        import time
        time.sleep(2)
        print("In a snow bank! Press enter to continue")
        chosen.add("joke")
    if pres in {'FACT','Fact','fact'}:
        print("Hippopotamus's have pink spit! Press enter to continue")
        chosen.add("fact")
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This helped